# API request logic giving error "Missing argument for parameter 'from' in call"

Tags: swift

I have json of the format:

```
{
    "status": "success",
    "data": {
        "place": {
            "id": 9
        }
    }
}
```

So I've created the following models:

**Response:**

```
struct Response: Codable {
    var status: String
    var data: Data
}
```

**Data:**

```
struct Data: Codable {
    let place: Place
}
```

**Place:**

```
struct Place: Codable {
    let id: Int
}
```

And here is my View Model class:

```
class PlaceViewModel: ObservableObject {
    private var cancellables = Set<AnyCancellable>()
    let userService: UserServiceProtocol
    @Published var response = Response()
    
    init(userService: UserServiceProtocol) {
        self.userService = userService
    }
    
    func fetchUsers() {
        userService.getUsers()
            .receive(on: RunLoop.main)
            .sink(receiveCompletion: { data in
                print(data)
        }, receiveValue: {[weak self] data in
            self?.response = data
        }).store(in: &cancellables)
        print(cancellables)
    }
}
```

Now following [this tutorial](https://medium.com/@islammoussa.eg/swiftui-and-combine-building-a-solid-network-layer-for-handling-api-requests-5ccce878212a) for making API requests, I'm getting an error:

> Missing argument for parameter 'from' in call

On the line:

```
@Published var response = Response()
```

What do I need to do to get rid of this error?

Comment: You can't just create a `Response` without parameters in the initializer. Maybe you want `@Published var response: Response?`?

Comment: @jnpdx If I make that optional, I get  error `No exact matches in call to instance method 'appendInterpolation'` on the line `Text("Place name: \(viewmodel.response?.data.place.id)")` in my View class.

Comment: Right, you'd have to handle the Optional. Do you know how to use `if let`?

Comment: `Response()` means `Response.init()`. `Response` doesn't have a `init()` method. It's a struct that needs values for `status` & `data`. There is an implicit `func init(status: String, data: Data)`, but no `init()`. That's why you get the error. There is also the implicit `init(from decoder: Decoder)` since it's Codable (hence Decodable).

Comment: Unrelated but avoid `struct Data`, avoid naming struct that already exists in Swift Foundation (since hence the name, it's a base), and it's more a less a "high level class" for "array of bytes". Else, you might need to always stipulate which `Data` you're thinking of using: `Swift.Data` or `YourFrameworkOrApp.Data`. You can name it `Datum` if you prefer.

Comment: After changing `Data` to `Datum` as recommended, just put this in your `struct Response`,
             `init() {
                 self.status = ""
                 self.data = Datum(place: Place(id: 0))
             }`